# Log4Net with WCF Running As Service

Tags: windows, wcf, windows-services, log4net

I am running a WCF Service as Windows Service.
I am having trouble getting log4net to do any actual logging

In what app.config should I place my configuration code for log4net.

The Service Host app.config the Service app.config or the underlying methods that the Service Calls?

-b

Comment: One thing I do is use a log4net config file and load it directly rather than trying to use app.config.  But my guess is the Service Host app.config would be the one that gets used.

Comment: Can you provide the details on you would do this?
A link would suffice.

Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: See this part in the link: XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(args[0]));  Of course you could replace args[0] with a filepath.
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into design issues like this when I was writing my own logging system. An app.config for a dll assembly won't load. The executable for your app/service/etc. is what loads and ignores the dll config. You will have to either implement your own read/write/load/etc config code or just set all config values into the service's app.config (much better idea if possible).

Comment: Yes, I have done this. Placing all the log4net config code in the Service as well as the Service Host .config.

It doesn't seem to be picking up either.